# Parsing Panda to_dict

Tags: python, pandas, list, dictionary

I have data is being fetch via API, but the data is in HTML format, so I used panda to convert the HTML to to_dict but when fetching the data in Django, it adds wraps around with string, which I'm not able to use the for loop to parse the data. How to remove the string so that I can fetch data.

Data:

```
output = fetchdata(datacenter)

    ## Dict format to fetch
    context = {
        'datacenter': datacenter,
        'output': output
    }
Here is the below OUTPUT:

{'datacenter': 'DC1', 'output': b"[{'Device': 'device01', 'Port': 'Ge0/0/5', 'Provider': 'L3', 'ID': 3324114459135, 'Remote': 'ISP Circuit', 'Destination Port': 'ISP Port'}, {'Device': 'device02', 'Port': 'Ge0/0/5', 'Provider': 'L3', 'ID': 334555114459135, 'Remote': 'ISP Circuit', 'Destination Port': 'ISP Port'}]\n"}
```

I would like to garb data from the output and present in Table format

Answer (score 0):

The output should be json object, so:

```
import json

json.loads(output)
```

It must work.

Comment: I tried the first thing, and didn't work. Issue with running python script via Django dict but it convert whole data into string. Not sure how to get the data from the dict